# Jupyter Lab / Notebook won't open

Tags: jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc

Recently I've been working on top of a PySpark instance hosted on DataProc using JupyterLab. Today I've been unable to connect to my instance.

The typical path I take is:

`DataProc -> Cluster_name -> Web Interfaces -> JupyterLab`

For the past 12 Hours all instances I have running PySpark and containing a Jupyter connection have been returning a 500 from Google.

```
500. That’s an error.

That’s all we know.
```

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Does anyone know of any work arounds?

Comment: If you `gcloud dataproc clusters describe` what is the full subminor image-version being used? Are you using the `global` multiregion or a regional endpoint (what region if so)?

Comment: @DennisHuo Interesting, running ```gcloud dataproc clusters describe``` yields no results (cluster not found) whereas other clusters I have without Jupyter enabled return their description. I am able to submit jobs to these clusters though and they run successfully.

Comment: You probably have the cluster running in a different regional endpoint that your other clusters in that case -- keep in mind that the "global" Dataproc region is a different universe from each regional Dataproc region like "us-central1" or "europe-west1". The Cloud Console UI should show both the GCE zone as well as the Dataproc "region" of all your clusters since it will fanout to all the regions to get an aggregated list; you should be able to then specify `--region` in `gcloud dataproc clusters describe` to talk to the correc tregion.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Putting your code in the GCS folder lets you access the code with jupyter lab in different clusters. If you were lucky enough to have your code there before your cluster became non-responsive, then you can switch clusters or create a new cluster and access your code in jupyter lab on another cluster. Best of luck.